Why are Besov norms weighted by powers of 2?
For $p, r \in [1, \infty]$, $s \in \mathbb{R}$ and $u$ a tempered distribution we can define the Besov norm $\|\cdot\|_{B_{p,r}^s}$ as follows:
$$\|u\|_{B_{p,r}^s} := \Big\|\big(2^{js}\|\Delta_ju\|_{L^p}\big)_{j \in \mathbb{Z}}\Big\|_{\ell^r(\mathbb{Z})}$$
where $\Delta_j$ is the operator projecting onto the $j$th dyadic block used in the Littlewood-Paley decomposition.
Why do we weight the norms $\|\Delta_ju\|_{L^p}$ by $2^{js}$ in this definition?

Note you have one too many power of $r$. If you take the $\ell^r$ norm outside you should only weight by $2^{js}$ inside. Then note that the littlewood-paley projection is approximately a localisation in frequency space at scale $2^{j}$ so this definition is really about how you have to weight the frequencies to achieve summability. In particular, if you built littlewood-paley blocks using a tryadic decomposition of unity (rather than dyadic), the appropriate weight would be powers of $3$

@RhysSteele Thanks for catching that, I have corrected my post. I think I am missing something obvious here but why is the series not summable without the weight $2^{js}$ and why does this specific choice come from using a dyadic decomposition?

To be more precise, I meant the series of $L^p$-norms of Littlewood-Paley blocks as appearing in the definition of the norm. The sum of projections converges in the sense of distributions for arbitrary tempered distributions $u$.
As for the choice of weight, $\Delta_j u = \varphi(2^{-j} D) u = 2^{jd} h(2^j \cdot) \ast u$ for some functions $\varphi$ and $h$ so that the natural scale is in powers of $2^j$. Maybe its a good idea to compute $|\Delta_j u|_{L^p}$ for some simple examples of $u$ (maybe starting with $u = \delta_0$) to get a handle on how that happens?

@RhysSteele Thank you, I played around with some simple examples of $u$ and I see how the scale $2^j$ naturally appears, but since this property is already part of the $\Delta_ju$ why do we need to explicitly add this to the definition? Why not, for example, define the Besov norm as $\Big|\big(|\Delta_ju|{L^p}\big){j \in \mathbb{Z}}\Big|_{\ell^r(\mathbb{Z})}$?

Try taking a derivative of an element of the space defined by your norm.

@RhysSteele Thanks I see the issue with it now. After playing around with it some more and reading other sources the conclusion I reached is that the $2^j$ is there so that the norm of $u(cx)$ differs from the norm of $u(x)$ by a factor of $c^{s-d/p}$ where $d$ is the dimension of the space. This gives us a Sobolev-like scaling. I think the only thing I'm missing is what would motivate one to place the regularity index $s$ in the exponent of $2^j$. In hindsight this makes sense, but I never would have thought to do this.
